# Employee document does not get updated in Firestore

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a document in firestore database. But following code does not update the document.

```
func UpdateEmployee(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    // Fetch employee ID from the query parameters
    empID := r.URL.Query().Get("empid")

    employeeId, err := strconv.Atoi(empID)
    fmt.Println(employeeId)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid Employee ID", http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.Printf("Invalid id was employeeId was provided on GetEmployee function call.\n\n")
        return
    }

    iter := client.Collection("ems").Where("ID", "==", employeeId).Documents(ctx)

    doc, err := iter.Next()

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Employee not found in db: %v\n\n", err)
        http.Error(w, "Employee not found", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    var employee models.Employee
    err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&employee)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid JSON", http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.Printf("\nInvalid JSON input for type Employee during controllers.CreateEmployee function call")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        return
    }

    err1 := validations.V.Struct(employee)

    if err1 != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid input for employee deatails", http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
        log.Printf("Invalid employee data input : occured while validating employee fields during controllers.CreateEmployee function call \n%v\n\n", err1)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        return
    }

    // Setting same employee id.
    employee.ID = employeeId

    // Define the updates in a variable
    updates := []firestore.Update{
        {Path: "employee_id", Value: employee.ID},
        {Path: "first name", Value: employee.FirstName},
        {Path: "last name", Value: employee.LastName},
        {Path: "email", Value: employee.Email},
        {Path: "password", Value: employee.Password},
        {Path: "phone no", Value: employee.PhoneNo},
        {Path: "role", Value: employee.Role},
        {Path: "salary", Value: employee.Salary},
        {Path: "birthdate", Value: employee.Birthdate},
    }
    _, err = doc.Ref.Update(ctx, updates)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to update employee: %v\n\n", err)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to update employee", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(doc)
    log.Printf("Employee updated with employee id: %v\n\n", employeeId)
}
```

I wanted to update my Employee resource in firestore collection through rest api. It gives me the correct reference of the document, but my document does not get updated.